# vue-cli-service build not reporting TypeScript errors that Visual Studio reports on .ts files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-cli

Vue 3 CLI 5 project.

For some in the team `vue build` will correctly fail with TS compilation errors on invalid `.ts` files - the same errors that VSCode reports.

For others on the team it succeeds where it should fail - but their IDE correctly reports the errors.

This is not `.vue` files, its on `.ts` files, so I don't think its anything to do with `vetur` or `volar` etc.

It sounds like different versions of `tsc` are being used - how can we check what version of `tsc` is used by `vue` and `vscode` ?

we checked versions of vue cli and node are the same - deleted node modules and re ran `yarn install`. `typescript` is a local dependency.